# How to solve this error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, string, casting, int, form-authentication

using forms authentication for my website and I get an error in

```
if (reader1.Read())
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
               1,
               tbDomainID.Text,
               DateTime.Now,
               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
               true,
               role = reader1.GetInt64(0),// this line
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
            hash);
            if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

when i convert it from `GetString(0)` to `GetInt64(0)` in will show me another error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'string'

can any one tell me where I am going wrong or what should I do.

I'm fetching integer value from the my database.

Comment: role is expecting a string. Your giving it an Int64(i.e. a long)

Comment: how to give role an integer value

Comment: I've written 3 comments, but to be honest, words fail me.... *vote to close* ...

Comment: Taken me a while to find something useful but **please** [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is the `UserData` parameter on the [FormsAuthenticationTicket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) on the [2nd constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kybcs83h.aspx).

As you can see from this expects a string, and `reader1.GetInt64(0)` will return a `long`.

The way to fix this is simply to call `.ToString()` like so:

```
role = reader1.GetInt64(0).ToString(),// this line
```

Although, I'm not sure I like to way you're setting the variable at the same time that you're passing it to the constructor. Personally, I'd do something like this:

```
if (reader1.Read())
{
    role = reader1.GetInt64(0).ToString();

    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        tbDomainID.Text,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        true,
        role,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        hash);

    if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: +1 Sometimes I despair, I really do. Ever feel like we're teaching the world basic programming techniques because they can't be bothered? :)